# How do I pipe to a file or shell program via Pythons subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, popen

I am working with some fairly large gzipped text files that I have to unzip, edit and re-zip. I use Pythons gzip module for unzipping and zipping, but I have found that my current implementation is far from optimal:

```
input_file = gzip.open(input_file_name, 'rb')

output_file = gzip.open(output_file_name, 'wb')

for line in input_file:
    # Edit line and write to output_file
```

This approach is unbearably slow – probably because there is a huge overhead involved in doing per line iteration with the gzip module: I initially also run a line-count routine where I - using the gzip module - read chunks of the file and then count the number of newline chars in each chunk and that is very fast!

So one of the optimizations should definitely be to read my files in chunks and then only do per line iterations once the chunks have been unzipped.

As an additional optimization, I have seen a few suggestions to unzip in a shell command via subprocess. Using this approach, the equivalent of the first line in the above could be:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

file_input = Popen(["zcat", fastq_filename], stdout=PIPE)

input_file = file_input.stdout
```

Using this approach input_file becomes a file-like object. I don't know exactly how it is different to a real file object in terms of available attributes and methods, but one difference is that you obviously cannot use seek since it is a stream rather than a file.

This does run faster and it should - unless you run your script in a single core machine the claim is. The latter must mean that subprocess automatically ships different threads to different cores if possible, but I am no expert there.

So now to my current problem: I would like to zip my output in a similar fashion. That is, instead of using Pythons gzip module, I would like to pipe it to a subprocess and then call the shell gzip. This way I could potentially get reading, editing and writing in separate cores, which sounds wildly effective to me. 
I have made a puny attempt at this, but attempting to write to output_file resulted in an empty file. Initially, I create an empty file using the touch command because Popen fails if the file does not exist:

```
call('touch ' + output_file_name, shell=True)

output = Popen(["gzip", output_file_name], stdin=PIPE)

output_file = output.stdin
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am using Python 2.7 by the way. Thanks.

Comment: if you have a performance question then create a minimal code example that can be used as a benchmark and state the desired goal (e.g., make it process (gzipped) data 100MB/s -- I doubt your disk is much faster than that -- there is no point to process (compressed) data faster than your disk can read/write it) --- and post it as a separate question.

Comment: Not really - just providing some background in case I am approaching this all wrong. What I really want to know is how to pipe to a shell program and in my case end up with a nice gzipped file. Read/write speed is not the issue here. It runs much faster if input and output files are plain text files, i.e. bigger files with more data to read/write. Overall it is also faster to unzip the input file in the shell, run the script, and zip the output file in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of how this can be done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

output_file_name = 'pipe_out_test.txt.gz'

gzip_output_file = open(output_file_name, 'wb', 0)

output_stream = Popen(["gzip"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=gzip_output_file)  # If gzip is supported

for line in output:
    output_stream.stdin.write(line + '\n')

output_stream.stdin.close()
output_stream.wait()

gzip_output_file.close()
```

If our script only wrote to console and we wanted the output zipped, a shell command equivalent of the above could be:

```
script_that_writes_to_console | gzip > output.txt.gz
```

Comment: 1- it is what I have suggested (you should give credit). 2- If your input is known in advance, you could use `gzip_process.communicate("\n".join(output))` instead 3- `gzip_output_file.close()` can be called immediately after `Popen()` in the parent 4- `gzip_process` is a better name than `output_stream` (gzip process is not a stream itself (it is not a file-like object), it is a process that may have stdin/stdout/stderr streams associated with it).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Here is the thing. When I finally cracked this it wasn’t because of your answer. I had totally misunderstood Popen, which is why I kept misunderstanding you. What worked was that I got totally pissed with your condescending tone and it pushed me to once again read the docs for the class until suddenly it all clicked and I could make my code work. I haven’t given you credit because to me, you answer wasn’t clear and I didn’t understand it. Do you understand that there is a difference between being correct and being clear? You should pay more attention to details like that.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I assume [this comment offends you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146282/how-do-i-pipe-to-a-file-or-shell-program-via-pythons-subprocess/38146835?noredirect=1#comment63747888_38146835). How would you convey the same information in a less *"condenscending tone"*?  (`output_file` and `gzip_output_file` are different names that refer to different objects -- you don't need to know *anything* about `subprocess` module to understand it)

Comment: It doesn't offend me. The object discussion that you seem to focus on was never the issue. I have no problem distinguishing the objects and I agree with you that you don’t have to understand subprocess or any other module for that matter in order to distinguish one object from another in Python. I misunderstood Popen and how to correctly use the available arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You meant `output_file = gzip_process.stdin`. After that you can use `output_file` as you've used `gzip.open()` object previously (no-seeking).

If the result file is empty then check that you call `output_file.close()` and `gzip_process.wait()` at the end of your Python script. Also, the usage of `gzip` may be incorrect: if `gzip` writes the compressed output to its stdout then pass `stdout=gzip_output_file` where `gzip_output_file = open(output_file_name, 'wb', 0)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the first part. I have edited it so it is more clear now. Also, I have added the call command, which was omitted before. I did close the file before and have tried the wait() method - still the file is empty.

Comment: @StephenMiller as I said already: your gzip usage may be incorrect. Use `Popen(["gzip"], stdout=gzip_output_file,...)`. Drop the `touch` call (it is useless).

Comment: Ok, I get you now. I tried your suggestion, but it seems the resulting object is not file-like. When I do: output_file.stdout.write(line) i get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'.

Comment: @StephenMiller please, read my answer carefully: `outfile_file = gzip_process.stdin` (you write to process' stdin, not stdout)

Comment: Well, I tried to follow your last comment - where you use stdout in your Popen call. Anyway, changing it back to stdin does not change it to a file-like object. I get the same error. Maybe I misunderstand you? When I used stdout in the Popen call - inspired by your comment - I obviously also changed output.stdin.write(line) to output.stdout.write(line). My concern is that a file-like object may only be created when you use PIPE?

Comment: @StephenMiller do you understand that `output_file` and `gzip_output_file` are different objects? You should pay more attention to details like that.

Comment: Indeed, if I follow you correctly gzip_output_file is a real file object and  output_file is supposed to be a file-like object created by Popen.